# Разделить на слоги

Tags: правописание

Подскажите пожалуйста делится ли " ее " на слоги или нет? Ведь имеется 2 гласные,а ум не делит...)))

Comment: Ум не делит, потому что согласных нет,но их нет только на письме, а при произношении есть:[jи(с призвуком э) - jо]

Answer (score 6):

В слове два слога, но переносить  слово нельзя.